# PeriodicWildCardError in snakefile

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I wrote the following snakefile to run Busco.

```
fasta_files = ["seq1", "seq2"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand('run_{file}/short_summary_{file}.txt', file = fasta_files)

rule run_busco:
    input:  
        fa="{file}.fasta", 
        lineage="home/nagaraap/Downloads/Softwares/busco-master/metazoa_odb9"
    output: "{file}"
    params:
        threads = 30
    log:
        "logs/{file}.log"
    shell:  "run_BUSCO.py -i {input.fa} -c {params.threads} -o {output} -m geno -l {input.lineage} &> {log}"
```

The error that I get is the following:

> PeriodicWildcardError in line 9 of *.smk: The value .fasta in wildcard
>   file is periodically repeated
>   (run_seq1/short_summary_seq1.fasta.fasta.fasta.fasta.fasta.fasta).
>   This would lead to an infinte recursion. To avoid this, e.g. restrict
>   the wildcards in this rule to certain values.

What does this mean ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, is that function def? If so please put that in your code because I am either seeing this for the first time or you forgot to put it there.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are running `run_busco` to generate sample.fasta. This means that the output of that file equals that string, so the wildcard `file` becomes sample.fasta.

You specified that the rule needs {file}.fasta as input, which when we expand our wildcard in, would become sample.fasta.fasta. The only rule which allows to generate this file is `run_busco`, which means that the wildcard `file` become sample.fasta.fasta. If we then fill {file}.fasta with this string, it would become...

All you have to do is change the output to not include the .fasta in the wildcard file:

```
rule run_busco:
    input:  
        fa="{file}.fasta", 
        lineage="home/nagaraap/Downloads/Softwares/busco-master/metazoa_odb9"
    output: "{file}.fasta"  <---- This should help!
    params:
        threads = 30
    log:
        "logs/{file}.log"
    shell:  "run_BUSCO.py -i {input.fa} -c {params.threads} -o {output} -m geno -l {input.lineage} &> {log}"
```

**edit:**

```
rule run_busco:
    input:  
        fa="{file}.fasta", 
        lineage="home/nagaraap/Downloads/Softwares/busco-master/metazoa_odb9"
    output: directory("run_{file}")
    params:
        threads = 30
    log:
        "logs/{file}.log"
    shell:  "run_BUSCO.py -i {input.fa} -c {params.threads} -o {output} -m geno -l {input.lineage} &> {log}"
```

Take a look at [directories as output](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs)

Comment: The problem with this busco is, the output is not {file}.fasta. Rather a directory name should be given and it generates a directory as "run_directoryname". In my example case run_{file}, in which it writes a series of files.

Comment: I kept getting MissingInputException. Then I changed the rule all: input: expand('directory('run_{input}', input=fasta_files). i.e pointed the ultimate output as directory itself. now it works. Next I will figure out a rule to extract an output file from each of these directory.